# addClass script not working on nav element

Tags: javascript, click, addclass, nav

I'm using the following script to change the class of clicked 'nav' elements to an 'active' class in my navbar.

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

It works when it's isolated in my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shockabout/ECshM/

But it's not working on my dev site:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102203801/HTML/index.html

I can't find what's preventing the 'active' class being applied. Do I have to add all the parent classes?

Comment: Check the console (F12)

Comment: Did you see anything in the console? I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is not working beacuse here anchor tag has to do two task at sametime
1. need to add class to it self 
2. need to take user to a div whose id is in href of anchor tag

you can try this code.

It will bind click function to activate anchor tag and then move user to new div by scroll effect.

```
$('nav li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var id=$(this).attr('href');
       scrollToId(id);
    });

    function scrollToId(id){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
                     }, 2000);    
    }
```

Comment: Taking this into account I have moved the class change into my smooth scroll script following the scroll. It works perfectly, no warnings or errors. Thanks again for your insight. I'm rebuilding everything from scratch to get everything in the right order and avoid conflicts. This helped me look to incorporate the function into the scroll function.

Answer (score 0):

I've just pasted your code into the console on the main site and it works perfectly. I did notice on the page that you've got a loader. Are you sure that the jQuery code isn't running BEFORE the nav element even exists?

What I think is happening, is the page loads, the DOM is then technically ready so jQuery binds the click event, but those elements don't exist because you've got other code loading the content, so jQuery doesn't actually bind anything.

Try changing it slightly to

```
$("body").on("click", "nav a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then it should work for you

Comment: This works perfectly, don't even need to include the active class to apply the remove. I placed the script inline just before the top nav. I having difficulty applying the class to the skewed box end on the right edge of the "Contact" nav. I have a script to transfer the states. Could be interfering, or I'm not selecting it properly. But as my design has changed I don't need the skewed div on the end anymore, so I'm going to remove it anyway. I'll refresh the html after a few more tweaks.

Comment: This worked only when I placed it directly above the nav elements in the HTML. It would not work in a linked file, so I rolled it into the my smoothscroll script.

Comment: hm that's a bit strange. the `on` method in jQuery should fire at any time regardless of where your code is placed. At least you've found a solution that works :)